# How to get the single screenshot between the given two Elements\Locators?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can Anyone say? So I need a single screenshot between these Two elements? Unfortunately, I can't able to get that
For Example:

```
IWebElement ApplicantOne = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span"));
Thread.Sleep(3000);

IWebElement ApplicantTwo = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span"));
Thread.Sleep(3000);

IWebElement ApplicantOne = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span"));
Thread.Sleep(3000);

IWebElement ApplicantTwo = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span"));
Thread.Sleep(3000);

//Screenshot ScreenShotOne = ((ITakesScreenshot)ApplicantOne).GetScreenshot();
//Thread.Sleep(2000);
//Screenshot ScreenShotTwo = ((ITakesScreenshot)ApplicantTwo).GetScreenshot();
//Thread.Sleep(200);

Point LocationOne = ApplicantOne.Location;
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Point LocationTwo = ApplicantTwo.Location;
Thread.Sleep(2000);

int x = Math.Min(LocationTwo.X, LocationTwo.X);
int y = Math.Min(LocationOne.Y, LocationTwo.Y);

int Width = Math.Abs(LocationTwo.X - LocationTwo.X) + Math.Max(ApplicantOne.Size.Width, ApplicantTwo.Size.Width);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
int Height = Math.Abs(LocationTwo.Y - LocationTwo.Y) + Math.Max(ApplicantOne.Size.Width, ApplicantTwo.Size.Width);
Thread.Sleep(3000);

Screenshot Screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

Bitmap originalImage = (Bitmap)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(Screenshot.AsByteArray);

Bitmap CroppedImage = originalImage.Clone(new Rectangle(x, y, Width, Height), originalImage.PixelFormat);

CroppedImage.Save("C:\\Users\\DCOHLO34\\Desktop\\Themes\\ScreenShot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

}
finally
{
    driver.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can't get the screenshot?" Is the application throwing an exception? Are you simply unable to get the elements in the screenshot?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GregBurghardt, For this scenario, I'm trying to get the Screenshot between the Two elements.  Can you please explain how to get that? Do I need to add any additional package for this?